# How to increase upload speed to azure media services from local system?

Tags: azure, azure-media-services

I am uploading videos from local system to azure media services. When uploading video with low size, it is uploading successfully. When I try to upload somewhat large size videos(100 MB like that), it takes more time and sometimes pages is not responding. But the video is uploaded to AMS.

Comment: please add details of how you are ingesting the files.

Comment: I am ingesting through my azure hosted website. The website is in azure. The media service ingesting code in WCF service, which is running in some other server (not using VM).                                                                            upload file from local system(using azure website) - > It will upload to intermediate server - > from that server one WCF service is running, which uploads the media file to azure media services.. It takes more time.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, I end up using the Server Explorer tool in Visual Studio to connect and upload that way. I've found it to be the fastest and most stable way of doing this.

[Here is a video tutorial on how to do that.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ff683677.aspx)  If you'd like more info from the docs, [you can find that here.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ff683677.aspx)